# Python script to read Gmail and export to CSV

Tags: python, csv, export

I am a newbie in Python programming.

Here is what am trying to achieve. I want this script to read my email address and select message from a particular sender and export the Subject and content of the email into a CSV file. The emails looks like this

```
"Subject: NEW DAILY CLOSE PRICES RECEIVED
 Email Body:
 AUD/USD Price: 0.7756
 EUR/USD Price: 1.2350
 GBP/USD Price: 1.4210 
 Time: 2018-03-21 20:00:00 (CET)"
```

I want the script to export the information to csv with the subject in a cell, the symbols (AUDUSD) in a cell, the prices in a cell and the time in a cell.
I'm stuck here in my code. I'd like the script to run continually.

```
import email
import imaplib
import os
import csv

email_id = "my_email"
password_id = "my_password"

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login (email_id, password_id)
mail.list()
mail.select('Inbox')
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "UNSEEN") # (ALL/UNSEEN)
i = len(data[0].split())
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Would you outline for readers what this script does, and what you are stuck on? Stack Overflow is not a free service to ask readers to "finish this script for me".

Comment: thank you halfer, i'm a newbie here too, thanks for the headup!!